# Change the value of a variable for a certain amount of time in Java

Tags: java, time

I am working on a fairly basic 2D java game. I was wondering if there is any way to change a variable (such as a boolean or int) for a certain period of time? I want to refrain from using for loops as they  would completely freeze my game for the period of time. The code would be something like this:

```
if(certainAbilityIsActivatedThatTakes5Seconds){

  // for 5 seconds{

  player1.isBeingAffectedByTheAbilityThatTakes5Seconds = true; }
```

Hopefully what I'm saying makes sense and is doable. Any help would be great. Right now I've managed to find a way for it to do this, but it relies on getting atleast 60 frames per second. I'm going to have to imagine that this is a shoddy practice. Any help would be great.

Comment: Well, since this is a game I assume you have a method that runs an Method in a long loop? So when you want to disable something you set a property to false and also store the time you set that property to false. Every time you pass through your loop you check if 5secods have passed since setting that variable and if that is true, reset the property. Does that make more or less sense. But be aware that if you are programming a game you should probably start using multiple threads that control different behaviors...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy solution, without resorting to threads or timers: instead of storing a `boolean`, store a `long` containing a timestamp that indicates when the ability was activated.

```
public class Ability {
      private static final int DURATION = 5000;

      private long activatedAt = Long.MAX_VALUE;

      public void activate() {
          activatedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
      }

      public boolean isActive() {
          long activeFor = System.currentTimeMillis() - activatedAt;

          return activeFor >= 0 && activeFor <= DURATION;
      }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by Max value on the second line?

Comment: Need to initialize it to a value that makes the `isActive()` method return `false` when the ability has never been activated. `Long.MAX_VALUE` is the maximum value for the `long` data type, and will always be bigger than the current timestamp. This makes it so that `isActive()` will return `false` by default.

Comment: Your way does not work. Subtracting system current time by Long.MAX_VALUE is going to give you a negative number which is always smaller than your Duration. Subtracting by Long.MIN_VALUE is going to overflow your number back to the negatives, again giving you true by default. And Subtracting by 0 is not going to be 100% accurate because there is an edge case where your (System.currentTimeMillis() - 0) will be <= to the duration at that time you check for it.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to start a new thread, set the variable to `true`, sleep for 5 seconds, set the variable back to `false`.

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        isBeingAffectedByTheAbilityThatTakes5Seconds = true;
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        isBeingAffectedByTheAbilityThatTakes5Seconds = false;
    }
}).start();
```

You may need to declare the variable as `volatile` so that all other threads would see the most recent value, or even better, use atomic variable (i.e. `AtomicBoolean`).

Answer (score 1):

A way you could do this would be to use the `java.util.Timer`. The timer allows us to schedule things to happen at certain times, or in a relative time from when we schedule a n`new TimerTask()`. Here is a quick implementation:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //This is where we tell it what to do when it hits 5 seconds
        }
    }, 5000);
```

I personally like this because it makes for more readable and obvious code, although both of the other solutions are valid and smart ways to approach this problem.

[Here is the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)